# JAVA GWT change widget color on click

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I have a custom class which extends Composite which extends widget. I have added a domHandler to handle ClickEvents. Currently I am setting the color to blue on click. The widget belongs to a panel which contains many of this same time of widget (TripEventItem). I want the color to change back to black text when a different widget is clicked on. Any idea how to do this?

```
final TripEventItem item = new TripEventItem(results.get(i), tripNumber);
        tripNumber++;
        item.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                finalResults.get(item.getTripId() - 1);
                List<LocationEvent> events = item.getTripEvent();
                listener.displayResults(new ArrayList(events));
                item.getElement().getStyle().setColor("blue");
            }
        }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an item is clicked, in your handler you can't know the state of the other items. You can keep all the items in a list. Then iterate this list and place your dom handlers. You `onClick` must iterate this list and restore the color. Then for the current item you apply the changes caused by the click event.

A rough example would be something like this

```
final List<TripEventItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {       
    final TripEventItem item = new TripEventItem(results.get(i), tripNumber);
    items.add(item);
}

for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    final TripEventItem item = items.get(i);
    item.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                TripEventItem otherItem = items.get(i);
                restore(otherItem);
            }

            item.getElement().getStyle().setColor("blue");
        }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());
}
```